# Pass Multiple parameters in a REST call

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs

My server code is as:

```
@POST
@Path("/getMapping")
public ListResponse getMapping(Long id, String name, String clientName, String instanceName) {
    ListResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = new ListResponse();
        List<Mappings> mappings = service.getMapping(id, name, clientName, instanceName);
        response.setStatusCode(SUCCESS);
        response.setMappings(mappings);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        setResponseErrors(response, e);
    }
    return response;
}
```

I am using Jersey REST client, but I dont think there is an option to have multiple params passed in the post method like:

```
ClientResponse clientResponse = webResource.type(XML_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, id, name, clientName, instanceName);
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

I could use **MultiValuedMap** or **@QueryParams** in this case, but there are other cases where multiple params are more complex Objects. Also, wrapping all in a "paramContainer" will be an inefficient solution since there are so many such methods with multiple params with different combinations.

(As an aside, why would REST not support multiple params?)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why the downvote? any particular reason?

Comment: the downvote is made by someone that thinks that your question is not very clear. (wasn't me by the way)

Comment: I've upvote, was a bit severe this downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how I'll do it
**SERVER CODE**

- 1.1 should have to use @FormParam in order to declare parameters in @FormDataParam
- 1.2 a POST is better if encrypted for that use @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)

you will have a server code like this :

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("/getMapping")
public ListResponse getMapping(@FormParam("id")Long id, @FormParam("name") String name, @FormParam("clientName") String clientName, @FormParam("instanceName") String instanceName) {
    ListResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = new ListResponse();
        List<Mappings> mappings = service.getMapping(id, name, clientName, instanceName);
        response.setStatusCode(SUCCESS);
        response.setMappings(mappings);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        setResponseErrors(response, e);
    }
    return response;
}
```

**CLIENT CODE**

```
Form form = new Form();
form.add("id", "1");    
form.add("name", "je@rizze.com");
form.add("clientName","firefox");
form.add("instanceName","node45343.rizze.com");

ClientResponse response = webResource
  .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE)
  .post(ClientResponse.class, form);
```

enjoy :)

Comment: Didn't quite work, but did give me a starting point. So thanks.
1. @FormParam is not supported so had to change to @FormDataParam (with new dependency)
2. There was media type conflict, so my server code now: `getMapping(Form form)` and I parse the form object in the method body. 

Not Ideal but works for now, until I can figure out the MediaType conflict.

Comment: This code has been compiling & executing on my dev env. Didn't undestand the media type conflict. Can you tell me exactly what is happening? Did you add to your App : register(MultiPartFeature.class);  please add : jersey-media-multipart as a dependency

Comment: MediaType conflict is due to (I think) I have @Produces(APPLICATION_XML) on the server code also. This seems to be causing the issue when my client code has .type as anything other than "XML". As I said, I am not accepting "form" object and then getting the values for the params in the code with "form.getFirst".

Comment: please use  produces like this :@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML}) and be sure to share a XML, if not will throw an error . MediaType is a javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

Comment: My bad ... I am using it as you have printed here: with the MediaType static constant. I just typed in the shortcut above :)

Answer (score 0):

**An addition to jeorfevre's answer above:**

In case you're using Jersey 1.x, this is how it works:

***Client: (pure Java):***

```
public Response testPost(String param1, String param2) {
    // Build the request string in this format:
    // String request = "param1=1&param2=2";
    String request = "param1=" + param1+ "&param2=" + param2;
    WebClient client = WebClient.create(...);
    return client.path(CONTROLLER_BASE_URI + "/test")
            .post(request);
}
```

***Server:***

```
@Path("/test")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void test(@FormParam("param1") String param1, @FormParam("param2") String param2) {
    ...
}
```